# Install the package that has been removed from the CRAN repository easily

Tags: r, installation, package

I want to use some packages, but they has been deleted in CRAN, though their formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive. Those packages are not in r-forge, too.

For instance, [dynamo](http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/web/packages/dynamo/index.html) and [gafit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gafit/index.html).

Though those packages have been removed, I find them still useful and can help me.

Is it possible to and how to install them **easily**? like `one_line_install('http://sss.tar.gz')`.

By the way, I may use them in Windows and/or in OS X. So the code should be designed as "multi-platform".

Answer (score 18):

It is easy using the `devtools` package as there is no need to download the package yourself. For example:

```
library(devtools)
install_url('http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dynamo/dynamo_0.1.3.tar.gz')
install_url('http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gafit/gafit_0.4.tar.gz')
```

I have no doubt this will be platform-independent.

The package has other related and useful functions such as `install_version`, `install_local`, `install_github`, etc.

Comment: I tried this, but failed both. For example, while installing gafit like the way you said:

    `*** arch - i386`
    `ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gafit'`
    `* removing 'C:/Users/yangzh/Documents/R/gafit'`
    `Error: Command failed (1)`

which means I cannot install it from source. I have to download the binary from [a backup repo](https://github.com/fyears/gafit-backup) and install that one.

Comment: @yangzh often the reason that packages are removed is that they don't compile

Comment: Also the dev on github version has a fix so that `install_version("dynamo", "0.1.3")` works

Comment: @hadley `install_version("dynamo", "0.1.3")` returns errors on my machine. :-(

Answer (score 8):

Depending on how far back you want to go, you can also use the [MRAN snapshot archive.](https://mran.microsoft.com/timemachine/) This is a sequence of daily snapshots of CRAN, going back to September 2014.

Eg to install a package from CRAN as it was on 30 June 2015:

```
install.package("my_package",
    repos="https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2015-06-30")
```

Comment: MRAN was retired on July 1, 2023. Are there any other repositories that can be used to install packages no longer in CRAN?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
install.packages('/path/dynamo_0.1.3.tar.gz', type = 'source')
```

where `path` is the path to the file you downloaded. That is it on a Mac! On Windows you have to play a bit with the slashes :-)

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, package gafit is available again without resorting to tricks.

As suggested above it was broken for some years as the core R system changed some packaging conventions. Hopefully fully fixed now.