# Converting from Gregorian to Hijri (Islamic) calendar in r

Tags: r

Is there any R function or packages that help me to convert Gregorian dates to Hijri (Islamic) calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the as.OtherDate function from the ConvCalender package.

Comment: ConvCalendar package doesnt exist in cran repository any more

Comment: Have a look at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655976/install-the-package-that-has-been-removed-from-the-cran-repository-easily