# Why these packages (metagen, metacont, metacor, metainc, or metabin) are not available anymore for R 4.3.2?

Tags: r, data-analysis, metafor

I want to plot pcurve, so I needed to use dmetar package, which calls for the packages in the title.
Is there a way to install them?

I've tried to install them using different methods with no success:

```
install.packages("metagen")
```

```
install.packages('path/metagen_1.0.tar.zip', repos=NULL, type='source')
```

```
install.packages("metagen", dependencies = TRUE)
```

```
pak::pkg_install("metagen", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: [metagen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metagen/index.html) was removed from cran 3.5 years ago. You can try to install from the archive (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655976/install-the-package-that-has-been-removed-from-the-cran-repository-easily)) or look for a replacement e.g. maybe [meta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/meta/index.html).

Comment: Seems there were a lot of errors due to breaking ggplot2 changes . See https://cran-archive.r-project.org/web/checks/2020/2020-07-05_check_results_metagen.html . A fix was offered https://github.com/00tau/metagen/issues/1 but seems not to have been implemented.

Comment: Someone could post comments as an answer ... there doesn't seem to be a canonical "how to figure out when & why a package was archived" dupe, so maybe someone could create one here?

Comment: FWIW, `metafor` is (IMO) the canonical/most widely used R package for meta-analysis, very complete/[lots of documentation](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/metafor). It might take some effort to figure out how to port your code over, but the methods that are available in these archived packages are *probably* available in `metafor` as well (and if you're missing some particular method you could [open an issue](https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor/issues))

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker! I do use metafor, but the latter lacks pcurve plotting functions, that's why I opted for meta and dmetar. I'd love to know if you have an updated package for pcurve.

Comment: I have no idea. "How do I create a p-curve?" wouldn't by itself be a good SO question, but if you started to implement your own and ran into trouble with some specific point you could certainly ask here ...

Comment: Looks like the `dmetar` package is available on [github](https://dmetar.protectlab.org/)

Comment: @G5W it does, but it has issues with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I used meta package instead, user20650, which include some of these functions.

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment.